# How to add a BR tag after fourth loop using Twig

Tags: php, loops, twig

I have this loop displaying six links from left to right. I would like to add a break after the fourth link but I'm new at Twig and I don't know how to add it in. Do I need another loop inside the For loop?

```
{% if contactLinks|length <= 6 %}
 {% for link in contactLinks %}                                             
  {{ link|raw }}
 {% endfor %}
{% elseif contactLinks|length >= 6 %}
 {% for link in contactLinks %}                                             
  {{ link|raw }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig has a special loop variable that you'll need to use. See here:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for link in contactLinks %}                                             
    {{ link|raw }}
    {% if loop.index == 4 %}
        <br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: This is going to throw multiple errors. You can't check for equality with a single = sign... You need to use ==. Also, you're missing the closing %} on the endif.